# Cómo comparar un JSON con una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo una tabla en MySQL, en donde guardo los artículos de mis vendedores, y lo que quiero hacer es un sistema en PHP que chequee si el vendedor tiene nuevos artículos, para lo cual recibo los artículos del vendedor en un JSON y los comparo con los que ya tengo almacenados en mi base de datos.

El asunto es que lo hago de 1 en 1 con un bucle. Quería saber si existe una forma más óptima de hacerlo, ya que si son 50 vendedores y cada uno tiene 100 articulos ya se imaginaran que son muchas consultas.

Aun no tengo escrito el codigo pero aqui dejo una idea de lo que hasta ahora tengo en mente:

```
$vendedores="select * from vendedores";

foreach( $vendedores as $vendedor ) 
{
    $json= "www.articulosdevendedor.com/json.php?id=$vendedor['id']"
    foreach($json['articulos'] as articulo)
       {
              "select * from articulo_vendedor where id_articulo='$articulo['id']";
               //aqui con un if realizaria las acciones si el articulo no se encuentra
       }
}
```

El codigo anterior es solo a modo ilustrativo ya que contiene varios errores. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de sistema es? y ¿En que lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Hola Carlos, estoy usando PHP y MYSQL, ahora lo añado a la descripcion.

Comment: Hola Mariano, agregue el código a la descripción. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema con arrays, he guardado los datos del json en un array y los datos de la base de datos en otro, luego los compare usando `array_diff` y listo, asi ahorro muchisimas consultas a la base de datos, de hecho realizo solo 1 por vendedor, espero a alguien mas le sirva la solucion. Saludos!!